# Liquid Cooling Temperature

Tags: temperature

I am having trouble understanding my temperature readout from lm-sensors.

I have a Gigabyte X570 Aorus Wifi Pro motherboard that has an EC_TEMP1 and EC_TEMP2. I plugged an inline temperature sensor for my cooling loop to EC_TEMP1.

Sensor: https://modmymods.com/phobya-g1-4-temperature-sensor-71170.html

Which line does this report?

```
k10temp-pci-00c3
Adapter: PCI adapter
Tdie:         +30.5°C  (high = +70.0°C)
Tctl:         +30.5°C  

acpitz-acpi-0
Adapter: ACPI interface
temp1:        +16.8°C  (crit = +20.8°C)

iwlwifi-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +28.0°C  

it8792-isa-0a60
Adapter: ISA adapter
in0:          +1.80 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +2.78 V)
in1:          +0.60 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +2.78 V)
in2:          +0.99 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +2.78 V)
+3.3V:        +1.68 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +2.78 V)
in4:          +1.80 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +2.78 V)
in5:          +1.19 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +2.78 V)
in6:          +2.78 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +2.78 V)  ALARM
3VSB:         +1.68 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +2.78 V)
Vbat:         +1.54 V  
fan1:        1646 RPM  (min =    0 RPM)
fan2:           0 RPM  (min =    0 RPM)
fan3:           0 RPM  (min =    0 RPM)
temp1:        +25.0°C  (low  = +127.0°C, high = +127.0°C)  sensor = thermistor
temp2:        -55.0°C  (low  = +127.0°C, high = +127.0°C)  sensor = thermistor
temp3:        +26.0°C  (low  = +127.0°C, high = +127.0°C)  sensor = thermistor
```

Answer (score 1):

Every temperature sensor shown has a temperature well below critical, so you're in good shape. As to which each line represents, that's something to ask [Gigabyte tech support](https://esupport.gigabyte.com/Login/Index?ReturnUrl=%2F) about. Some of them, e.g., temp2 in it8792-isa-0a60 are clearly spurious.